# How can I detect letters in an image with openCV?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I want to split my image into multiple region, where a region is equal to a letter.

My example image is
https://myinvoice.be.carrefour.eu/sites/all/themes/custom/myinvoice/images/ticket.jpg

The goal is to detect each letter individually. For example it would detect first the zone of C, then A, R, R and so on.

Any idea of a good algorithm / technique I could use to do that ?

I tought about ranging the pixel array, and when I found a pixel to follow the shape of pixels until I arrive at the beginning point. Save the min/max coordinate and then go to the next one by doing x + maxSHape or something like that but I am afraid it will take a very long time to analyse.

Comment: have a look at the text module under opencv contrib. The text module is used to perform optical character recognition, you probably need to get tesseract as well for that. https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

Comment: @lamandy I would have done that, but it's university project and we are not allowed to used OCR libs, to make us do some image processing and not just calling functions that do all the work.

Comment: Do you want to recognize what that letter is or only detecting the letters is enough?

Comment: @janu777 detecting the letter region is enough. I have already a good algorithm for recognize the letter afterward.

Comment: the image format are all the same (those tickets)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is that clear. Then that is easy.

```
1. Thresholding image to binary image (Otsu thresholding will work well)
2. Add some Deliation, Erosion to remove noise
3. Find contour from entire image
4. Add some are filter to select the specific font-characters
```

You can use opencv and python to implement those task.